# Using Dapper Rainbow with a Firebird database

Tags: c#, .net, firebird, dapper-rainbow

I'm currently trying to use Dapper rainbow as a wrapper for my Firebird database.

The problem is that it seems to be generating SQL for a different type of DB.

The SQL generated is:

```
select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = @name
```

Which is causing a "Dynamic SQL error" from Firebird since Firebird doesn't have an INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Here is my code:

```
public class USERI{
    public string ID { get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class DB : Database<DB> {
    public Table<USERI> users { get; set; }
    }

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string connString = String.Format(@"DataSource=localhost;Database={0};
                                    User Id=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey", dbLocation);

        var db = DB.Init(new FbConnection(connString), commandTimeout: 2);
        var users = db.users.First();

    }
}
```

I have used normal Dapper queries on my DB and it was succesful. How can I make the DB wrapper in Rainbow be aware of the DB type?

Comment: Looking at [its code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.Rainbow/Database.cs) and the SQL dialect it uses, Dapper Rainbow assumes you are using it with SQL Server. It doesn't seem to have support for other databases.

Comment: I didn't think to look in its code, since I thought if Dapper worked with Firebird so will Rainbow.